# How to run @QuarkusIntegrationTest in a Gradle project?

Tags: java, testing, integration-testing, quarkus

I want to run a Quarkus integration test in order to verify OpenAPI yaml generated from the source code. According to the documentation, [it should be possible](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus-integration-test) to do it using the `@QuarkusIntegrationTest` annotation. However the it is not explained how to mek it work.

> As a test annotated with @QuarkusIntegrationTest tests the result of the build, it should be run as part of the integration test suite - i.e. via the maven-failsafe-plugin if using Maven or an additional task if using Gradle.

Unfortunately, it is not clear what this means and how to configure that "additional task" in Gradle.

**Question:** How to run a Quarkus Integration Test in a Gradle project?

Answer (score 3):

If your `build.gradle` file contains

```
plugins {
    id 'io.quarkus'
}
```

then you should be able to run the `@QuarkusIntegrationTest` tests with

```
.\gradlew quarkusIntTest
```

Comment: with `quarkusIntTest`, before my `@QuarkusIntegrationTest` test are executed, my unit test are executed as well- How can I skip them?

Comment: .\gradlew -x test quarkusIntTest ?

Answer (score 1):

Running integration test will require the final artifact to be built.

Thus before running the test task, you will need to run a `quarkusBuild`. Once your app is build, and if your tests are in `src/test/java` you can simply run `gradle test` to run them.

In order to make sure your artifact is always available before you run your integration tests, you can create a new task of type test, that will depend on `quarkusBuild`, that would only run those tests. For example :

```
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    description = "Runs integration tests"
    group = "verification"
    useJUnitPlatform()

    // Include only integration test package
    include 'io/quarkus/gradle/integrationtest/*.class'
}

integrationTest.dependsOn(quarkusBuild)
```

or you can create a custom source set and put your test there, this is documented here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've used quarkus plugin to create a ready gradle project and the task to run integration tests was the command bellow, also check this [Sample project](https://github.com/mageddo/java-examples/tree/62bb380d161e16cfc40601d881f0338e8d8becf1/quarkus/quarkus-2-simple).

The tests looks like:

```
@QuarkusIntegrationTest
class SolverSystemIT {
....
```

The command to run this kind of test:

```
$ ./gradlew build testNative
> Task :testNative
Finished generating test XML results (0.001 secs) into: .../build/test-results/testNative
Generating HTML test report...
```